# Create dictionary where keys are from a list and values are the sum of corresponding elements in another list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists L1 and L2. Each unique element in L1 is a key which has a value in the second list L2. I want to create a dictionary where the values are the sum of elements in L2 that are associated to the same key in L1.

I did the following but I am not very proud of this code. Is there any simpler pythonic way to do it ?

```
L = [2, 3, 7, 3, 4, 5, 2, 7, 7, 8, 9, 4] # as L1
W = range(len(L)) # as L2

d = { l:[] for l in L }
for l,w in zip(L,W): d[l].append(w)
d = {l:sum(v) for l,v in d.items()}
```

**EDIT:**

**Q:** How do I know which elements of L2 are associated to a given key element of L1?

**A:** if they have the same index. For example if the element 7 is repeated 3 times in L1 (e.g. L1[2] == L1[7] == L1[8] = 7), then I want the value of the key 7 to be L2[2]+L2[7]+L2[8]

Comment: How do you know which elements of L2 are associated to a given key element of L1?

Comment: @eguaio if they are have the same index. For example if the element 7 is repeated 3 times in L1 (e.g. L1[2] == L1[7] == L1[8] = 7), then I want the value of the key 7 to be L2[2]+L2[7]+L2[8]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `enumerate()` in order to access to item's index while you loop over the list and use [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) (by passing the `int` as it's missing function which will be evaluated as 0 at first time) to preserve the items and add the values while encounter a duplicate key:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict

>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for i,j in enumerate(L):
...     d[j]+=i
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {2: 6, 3: 4, 4: 15, 5: 5, 7: 17, 8: 9, 9: 10})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the intermediate `dict` of `list`s you can use the `collections.Counter`:

```
import collections
L = [2, 3, 7, 3, 4, 5, 2, 7, 7, 8, 9, 4] # as L1
W = range(len(L)) # as L2

d2 = collections.Counter()
for i, value in enumerate(L):
    d2[value] += i
```

which behaves like a normal dict:

```
Counter({2: 6, 3: 4, 4: 15, 5: 5, 7: 17, 8: 9, 9: 10})
```

Comment: updated the answer to show the advantages of ``Counter`` over ``defaultdict``.

Comment: the last expression does not produce the same result as the solution you provided first. W[i] will not be the sum it will be the last value in W for the corresponding key.

Comment: yes I also noticed this shortly before you commented, I'll see if I can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this may help you.

```
L = [2, 3, 7, 3, 4, 5, 2, 7, 7, 8, 9, 4] # as L1
dict_a = dict.fromkeys(set(L),0)
for l,w in enumerate(L):    
    dict_a[w] = int(dict_a[w]) + l
```